Determine the sample space if the die is rolled once, and rolled again if the result is greater than 4
Let $r \in \{1, \dots , 6\}$, then if $r \leq 4$ we get the events $\{1, 2, 3, 4\} = A$.
If $r \geq 5$ then we have the events $$\{(x_1​, x_2,…,x_n) \colon x_i∈\{5,6\} \text{ for } i<n \text{ and } x_n \in \{1,2,3,4\}\} = B$$
So an example of $B$ is $B = \{5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, \underbrace{...}_{\text {all 5s or 6s, n-1 of them in total}}, 1\}$
So do we get the full sample space with $\Omega = A \cup B$ ?

The rules are not clear.  Do you keep on rolling until you get $≤4$ or do you stop after the second toss no matter what?

@lulu it just says "if you get $n > 4$ roll again", so i went with the (harder) assumption that they mean keep on rolling until you get $\leq 4$. if they meant stop after the second toss, then instead of n-tuples we would just have ordered pairs i guess?

So then you are missing the infinite paths where you never get a value less than $4$.  Of course, these have probability $0$ but they are still possible paths.

The way you described the event $B$ is confusing, as $n$ is not quantified.  Better, I think, to omit the $A,B$ distinction and, instead, introduce events $A_n$ which end on the $n^{th}$ toss.

@lulu i see. if I define $B$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$ does that essentially do what you're suggesting-introducing events $A_n$ which end on the nth toss?

You can indeed clarify your definition of $B$ to indicate that you are including all $n>1$, but I think the $A,B$ distinction is not really important.  The paths I proposed, $A_n$  get all of those.  Again, you'll also need $A_{\infty}$ to allow for the infinite paths.  Probability $0$ or not...the sample space ought to include every possible outcome.

@lulu i made an edit to the post, hope this is what you had in mind

Again, you need to quantify $n$ before using it.  You can't just introduce an unspecified variable into your definition.  If you want to do all the $n$ at once, you need to say something like "there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that..."

Something like:  For $n\in \mathbb N$, we define $A_n$ to be the set of paths $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ such that $x_i\in {5,6}$ if $i<n$ and $x_n\in {1,2,3,4}$.

@lulu perhaps you didn't see it, but I did put $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ and the end of the line where I define $A_n$, is this not enough? sorry if this is annoying and many thanks for the good advices&help so far!

Look at my proposed phrasing to see the difference.  The point is that, for a given natural number $n$, we are defining a set of paths we call $A_n$.  $n$ is quantified at the start, not in the middle, of the definition.

@lulu well, as I see it it's actually at the end not middle :D but I get your point, makes sense. thanks!

Following lulu's advice from comments, for $n \in \mathbb N$ define $$A_n = \{(x_1​, x_2,…,x_n) \colon x_i∈\{5,6\} \text{ for } i<n \text{ and } x_n \in \{1,2,3,4\}\} $$
then $$\Omega = \Bigr( \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n \Bigr) \cup A_\infty$$
where $A_\infty = \{(x_1​, x_2,…) \colon x_i∈\{5,6\} \}$ takes care for the cases where we never roll $r \leq 4$.
